# Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL

Tags: .net, sql-server, exception, ado.net, windows-services

I am developing a windows service to transfer the datas from one remote database to another database.

I am getting the following error when i try to connect to the database. This connection string working perfect from the web application.

I am getting this error only when i try to connect the database using the windows service.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at WindowsService.Program.timer1_Elapsed(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Trigger\WindowsService\WindowsService\Program.cs:line 93
```

Connectionstring i am using:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TAG2;Initial Catalog=A10;User ID=sa; pwd=root;Integrated Security=False");"
```

Answer (score 3):

The sql server is most likely set to "windows authentification only" mode.

See this [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-ver15) to resolve your error.

Comment: provided link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

As a default installation, I think, it is set to only allow Windows Authentication. However, using Sql Server Management Studio (if used), you can enable Sql Server Authentication. Follow link here http://cherupally.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/user-is-not-associated-with-trusted-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the settings on your database - you probably need to change the Authentication methods from
'Windows only' to 'SQL Authentication'

You can read more [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889615)

Comment: I made it to the mixed mode still i am getting the same error.